# Why am I getting this error with the perl module Catalyst::Model::Adaptor?

Tags: perl, catalyst

I'm trying to get an old project I was handed to run and I'm running into a problem with the model we have for TheSchwartz.  The code looks exactly the same as a bunch of other examples to do similar things I've found online. The code is also pretty simple;

```
package MyApp::Model::TheSchwartz;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

extends 'Catalyst::Model::Adaptor';

__PACKAGE__->config( class => "TheSchwartz" );

sub mangle_arguments
{
  my ($self, $args) = @_;
  if($args->{databases})
  {
    if(ref($args->{databases}) eq 'HASH')
    {
      my %db = %{ $args->{databases} };
      $args->{databases} = [ \%db ];
    }
  }
  return %{ $args }
}
1;
```

The error I get is

```
Couldn't instantiate component "MyApp::Model::TheSchwartz", "unknown options args, catalyst_component_name, class at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Catalyst/Model/Adaptor/Base.pm line 27."Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Module/Runtime.pm line 317.
 at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Catalyst/Script/Server.pm line 242.
```

I've tried removing the mangle_arguments function, I've tried removing the Moose usage and using "use base" instead.  I always end up with the same error, and I'm really having a hard time even grokking the error message.  I don't see catalyst_component_name defined anywhere in my code so it must be passed down from Catalyst::Model::Adaptor, but.. why doesnt it work?

EDIT:

here's the relevant config section:

```
<Model::TheSchwartz>
    <args>
        verbose 1
        <databases>
            dsn     dbi:mysql:host=db.vpn;dbname=theschwartz
            user    user
            pass    password
        </databases>
    </args>
</Model::TheSchwartz>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is downright silly and one of those things you try just to say you tried it without expecting it to work, but somehow this actually seems to have fixed it.

```
delete $args->{class};
delete $args->{catalyst_component_name};
delete $args->{args};
return %{ $args }
```

The model still seems to work properly, though I really expect to have broken something by just arbitrarily deleting the keys that were erroring like that.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to create a Moose class and it's not compatible with the
regular [Catalyst::Model::Adaptor](http://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aModel%3a%3aAdaptor) usage; and you are not, in your
example, using any Moose functionality anyway. This is probably,
lightly tested, what you really want.

```
package MyApp::Model::TheSchwartz;
use parent "Catalyst::Model::Adaptor";

__PACKAGE__->config( class => "TheSchwartz" );

sub mangle_arguments {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;
    if ( $args->{databases} )
    {
        if (ref ( $args->{databases} ) eq "HASH" )
        {
            my %db = %{ $args->{databases} };
            $args->{databases} = [ \%db ];
        }
    }
    return %{ $args }
}

1;
```

[parent](http://metacpan.org/module/parent) is sometimes considered preferable to [base](http://metacpan.org/module/base) but they are almost interchangeable.

#### Update, 26 July 2012

FWIW, this is a working version of TheSchwartz being used as a model in one of my apps; it's been in production for... 2 years I think. The Cat version is a few back but not  2 years old. I'm sorry I didn't dig it up before–

```
package MyApp::Model::TheSchwartz;
use parent "Catalyst::Model::Adaptor";
__PACKAGE__->config( class => "TheSchwartz" );

sub mangle_arguments { %{$_[1]} }

1;

__END__
# In MyApp.pm

"Model::TheSchwartz" => {
    args => {
        verbose => 1,
        databases => [{
            dsn => "dbi:mysql:MyAppDB;host=my_host",
            user => "something",
            pass => "somethingsecret",
            }],
            }
},
```

The [Config::General](http://metacpan.org/module/Config%3a%3aGeneral) format you're using is probably to blame your ref/HASH handling. You can see from my `mangle_arguments` that if the args are properly formed, there is no need to do anything with them at all but flatten them to the list TheSchwartz expects.

Comment: I still get the same error, I'm beginning to wonder if its just a problem with my Catalyst install. All of this is on a fresh ubuntu 12.04LTS install with all the perl modules installed off CPAN, so maybe one of the newer versions of the libs introduced some kind of incompatibility.

Comment: Are you doing anything unusual in your configuration arguments? Can you add *all* the config you are using to the OP? Whether from MyApp.pm or my_app.conf|yaml|etc.

Comment: I added just the segment for this model-- The full config is 90 lines. Should I add the whole thing there or is that too much info and something I should just pastebin?